# Numpy can't be imported in Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

When trying to import numpy in spyder i get the following error message:

`ImportError:`

`IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!`

`Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.`

`- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.`

`- If you have already done that, then:`

`1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "/home/sltzgs/anaconda3/bin/python",and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.2" you're trying to use.`

`2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log`

`- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try`git clean -xdf`(removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.`

`Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.`

`Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`

However, importing in a jupyter notebook works fine. How is that possible? 
I have uninstalled/installed numpy a few times by now and also made sure, that the sys.paths are identical.

Any help appreciated. In case any additional information is required I would happily help out. Thanks.

Some essentials:
python 3.7
Spyder 3.3.6 
numpy 1.17.2

Comment: From the message, the error is coming from Python 3.6, but you're using 3.7, yes?  Make sure Spyder is looking at the correct Py install.  Additionally, have a look in your `/.../site-packages/numpy/core` and see if `_multiarray_umath` exists for both installations.  This should help get you started in tracking it down ...

Comment: Please report the error as text.

Comment: Do you use spyder alone (then install via pip) or do you use it via anaconda?

Comment: @Mathieu > via anaconda

Comment: Did you install numpy via pip or anaconda ? If you installed it via pip, then that's why. you need to use conda install commands to install libraries within the anaconda environments.

Comment: I have tried both actually - conda and pip install for numpy - issue still there... however, what seems weird to me is that I can import numpy in jupyter notebooks without problems... only spyder doesn't allow it

Comment: I think you corrupted your Anaconda installation by using pip to install numpy, so you should uninstall it and reinstall it again.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as the OP.  I did a fresh installation of Anaconda and see the same error message when attempting to import numpy by opening a command prompt and starting up a Python interpreter.  Strangely, I can import numpy via a Jupyter notebook...

Comment: I "solved" the issue eventually by following @CarlosCordoba's advice of re-installing my Anaconda. Since you just did exactly that I am not sure if another re-install will help you....

Answer (score 1):

Problem did not occur again after re-installing Anaconda. Thanks @CarlosCordoba.